# Obtaining Marginal Forecasts

Tags: logistic, predictive-models

I am trying to make predictions on a dummy variable. What I am predicting is whether or not a separate variable ever changes from a zero to a 1 in a year from the observation date. The dummy variable is a 1 if the separate variable is ever a 1 in that year and a 0 if it never becomes a 1. This is easy enough to do with a logistic regression, my question is how I can get marginal predictions using the same model. By marginal predictions I mean I want to be able to predict the probability of this separate variable ever being a 1 in the period between 1 year from observation date and 2 years from observation date.

For this problem, I cannot use recursive forecasting (feeding the predicted values of the model and predicted values for all predictors back into the model to get the next period prediction); I can't get predicted values for the predictors. I am considering direct forecasting. What I mean by this is creating a new model for each forecasting horizon (in this case one model for 1 year ahead, one model for 2 years ahead) and then estimating each model separately on present data. My problem is that this gives me forecasts for the periods present to 1 year and present to 2 years but I want forecasts for the periods present to 1 year and 1 year to 2 years.

My immediate response to this problem was to simply subtract the first year forecast probability from the first two year forecast probability to get the difference. My gut tells me this is wrong though, I'm not sure that I can simply subtract these probabilities especially since the first two year forecast probability is dependent on the first year probability.

How can I get at the one year from now to two years from now probability forecast?